# SAS decimal precision and writing to database

Tags: sas, precision

Good day,

I had this issue where I was writing some numbers to database, which should have had value `0.1` in SAS, but for some bizarre reason appeared as `0.09` in SQL database. When I manually checked the dataset it showed `0.10` in format *12.2*.

So what I do is check if the values are actually 0.1 or somewhat below this:

```
data _checking;
    set publish_data;
    if value < 0.1;
    dummy = value*10000000;
run;
```

It appeared that number of observations fulfill the first condition. Ok... That explains why the values come out as 0.09. Rounding issue.

However, all *dummy* values come out as integers. I tried 10, 100, 1k, 10k all appear to come out as integers. (1, 10, 100 ...)

Next step I try:

```
data _checking2;
    set _checking;
    if dummy<10; /*Depending on the factorial*/
run;
```

This is consistent. Dummy retains the value 'a little below the value shown'.

I solved the issue by `round(value,.1);`

**Questions**:

1. How to observe the actual value stored in dataset? (Especially in case 'a little below')
2. If first condition if is true, then how can the checking with `dummy` still show integer values. (Because in computers epsilon has to have actual value)

   2.b Or is this just a display issue? Or does SAS has flag for 'value minus epsilon'?

Comment: SAS represents numbers in binary (using the IEEE floating point standard).  "Although the IEEE platforms use the same set of specifications, you might occasionally see varying results between the platforms due to compiler differences, and math library differences".  http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0ji1unv6thm0dn1gp4t01a1u0g6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

The most precise and least human way to see the actual value is to observe the underlying IEEE bytes using `HEX` format.

**Answer 2:**

The default format for those new dummy variables is `BEST12.`, so you won't see any small offsets if they are smaller than what best12. will show, or more precisely epsilon < 1e-(12-log10(x)).  The SAS format could be considered a display issue in this case.

If your use case is that of a 'shown' value must be the actual value sent to a remote database then you will want to use `ROUND` prior to populating the remote tables.

```
data x;
  x = 1/3; output;
  x = 0.1 - 1e-13; output;
  format x 12.2;
run;

data y;
  set x;

  put x= x= HEX16.;

  xhex = x;
  format xhex hex16.;

  array dummy dummy1-dummy13;
  do _n_ = 1 to 13;
    dummy(_n_) = x * 10**_n_;
  end;
run;

proc print data=y;
run;

data z;
  do p = 0 to 10;
  do q = 1 to 15;
    array z z1-z15;
    z(q) = 10**p + 10**-q;
  end; output;
  end;
  drop p q;
run;

==== LOG ====
x=0.33 x=3FD5555555555555
x=0.10 x=3FB9999999997D74

==== PRINT ====
Obs            x             xhex  dummy1  dummy2  dummy3  dummy4  dummy5    dummy6    dummy7

 1          0.33 3FD5555555555555 3.33333 33.3333 333.333 3333.33 33333.33 333333.33 3333333.33
 2          0.10 3FB9999999997D74 1.00000 10.0000 100.000 1000.00 10000.00 100000.00 1000000.00

Obs    dummy8         dummy9          dummy10        dummy11         dummy12           dummy13

 1  33333333.33    333333333.33    3333333333.3    33333333333    333333333333    3.3333333E12
 2  10000000.00    100000000.00    1000000000.0    10000000000    100000000000    999999999999
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can try a different format.  try `32.31` or `best32.`
2. Subtract `0.1-value` and look at the result.  Again, use a format with a lot of decimal places.

You are probably not seeing the value in the `dummy` variables because the epsilon is very small and the dummy is still getting rounded for display.

3. Try `dummy=value*1e16` or higher.

Numbers in SAS are C doubles, fwiw.